# AIM <-> Google Talk... how?

Tags: google-talk, aim

How do I allow someone that uses the AIM desktop client to chat with someone else using the Google Talk desktop client?  The trick is that I don't want to have them have to change clients.

Long ago I used Trillian...  then Pidgin and now Meebo.  But these are not solutions to the question.  Also note that the Google client is not the web gadget.

Thanks,
-kyle

Comment: Definitely SuperUser material.

Comment: Agreed and voted wit @Adrian -- stackoverflow is about **developing software**, that's NOT what you're hoping to to here, right?!

Comment: My apologies for the misuse.  *blush*  Thanks for the pointer to SuperUser...  question reposted there:

http://superuser.com/questions/86387/aim-google-talk-how

(just in case you have an answer) :]